# How to automatically display categories on the home page

Tags: php, wordpress

how can we automatically display the categories and posts published in that category on the main page by adding a category? I always have to write a special code to display each category, and if the category name or slug changes, it will be removed from the main page. please guide me.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <?php
            $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'books' );
            $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);
            $cat_name = get_cat_name($category_id);
        ?>
        <header class="border-bottom border-secondary section-header mb-3 float-right w-100">
            <h3 class="text-right text-secondary h5 mb-0 float-right">
                <?php echo $cat_name; ?>
            </h3>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" class="btn btn-outline-info float-left mb-1">
                read more
            </a>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should call a category by ID using the function `get_category()`, then changing the name or the slug won't effect your site.

Comment: can you give a sample or share the guide link?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category/

Check the example by hearvox. after using his example, you'll get an object containing all the data you need and you can call it by using $category->name; in order to get the name for example.